# Text::SpellChecker module and Unicode

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, perl-module

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::SpellChecker;

my $text = "coördinator";
my $checker = Text::SpellChecker->new( text => $text );

while ( my $word = $checker->next_word ) {
    print "Bad word is $word\n";
}
```

Output: `Bad word is rdinator`

Desired: `Bad word is coördinator`

The module is breaking if I have Unicode in `$text`. Any idea how can this be solved?

I have Aspell 0.50.5 installed which is being used by this module. I think this might be the culprit.

Edit: As [`Text::SpellChecker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::SpellChecker) requires either [`Text::Aspell`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Aspell) or [`Text::Hunspell`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Hunspell), I removed `Text::Aspell` and installed `Hunspell`, `Text::Hunspell`, then:

```
$ hunspell -d en_US -l < badword.txt
coördinator
```

Shows correct result. This means there's something wrong either with my code or Text::SpellChecker.

---

Taking Miller's suggestion in consideration I did the below

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::SpellChecker;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(utf8)";
my $text =  "coördinator";
my $flag = utf8::is_utf8($text);
print "Flag is $flag\n";
print "Text is $text\n";
my $checker = Text::SpellChecker->new(text => $text);
while (my $word = $checker->next_word) {
    print "Bad word is $word\n";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Flag is 1
Text is coördinator
Bad word is rdinator
```

Does this mean the module is not able to handle utf8 characters properly?

Comment: I'd recommend properly handling utf8 with regard to your source file and your output streams.  However, this issue also occurs while doing such things and using Aspell 0.60.6.1.

Comment: Hi Miller, see the updated question.

Comment: Could you add printing `$ENV{LANG}` to your test?

Comment: ö is a German diacritics and I think can be handled by latin-1 so you actually don't need UTF-8 ..if you have 2 byte chars.. also as mentioned in previous comments UTF data needs to be treated correctly during STDIN and STDOUT also you need support from the vendor.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: `en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 4):

It is Text::SpellChecker bug - the current version assumes ASCII only words.

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BDUGGAN/Text-SpellChecker-0.11/lib/Text/SpellChecker.pm

```
#
# next_word
# 
# Get the next misspelled word. 
# Returns false if there are no more.
#
sub next_word {
    ...
    while ($self->{text} =~ m/([a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?)/g) {
```

IMHO the best fix would use per language/locale word splitting regular expression **or** leave word splitting to underlaying library used. `aspell list` reports `coördinator` as single word.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the problem. I tried changing it to `while ($self->{text} =~ m/(\p{L}+(?:'\p{L}+)?)/g) {` and it seems to be working fine now. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

I've [incorporated](https://github.com/bduggan/Text-SpellChecker/commit/385c6a8ca60e0009e96220107ed8ca05be841d44) Chankey's solution and released version 0.12 to the CPAN, give it a try.

The validity of diaeresis in words like coördinator is interesting.  The default aspell and hunspell dictionaries seem to mark it as incorrect, though some [publications](http://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/the-curse-of-the-diaeresis) may disagree.

best,
Brian